# PDFBox - PDF not visible in iOS

Tags: pdf, groovy, pdfbox

I am bringing in a "fillable" form in PDFBox and filling in the input fields, then setting these fields to read-only.  We are doing this so the PDF is easily fillable for us and not for the final user.

The problem I am having is when the user opens the PDF in iOS (and in some cases Android) the fillable fields are not visible.  Everything else is still there, just not the fields filled in.  And if I open the same pdf that doesn't work for them on any laptop/desktop, everything is there.

Am I using fillable fields for the wrong reason, is there a better way of doing this, or is there a way I can make these fields visible to the user's on iOS?

Here is a quick example of what I am doing:

```
public PDDocument fillDynamicPDF(form, field, entry){
try{
    PDDocument pdDoc = PDDocument.load(new File("form"))
    PDDocumentCatalog pdCatalog = pdDoc.getDocumentCatalog()
    PDAcroForm acroForm = pdCatalog.getAcroForm()
    acroForm.getField(field).setValue(entry)
    acroForm.getField(field).setReadonly(true)
    return pdDoc
}catch(e){
    log.error e
    return null
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On iOS it depends on the application you use to view the PDF files. If the application uses the CGPDF API or the QuickLook framework then the fields are not displayed because these frameworks cannot display PDF annotations (fields use widget annotations). 
If you use Adobe Reader to view the file then the fields are visible because it uses its own rendering engine.
A solution is to flatten the form fields instead of making them read-only. This operation merges the field content with the page content and they will be visible on iOS no matter what application is used to view the file.

Comment: How do I flatten them using PDFbox?
Or is there some other way to flatten them?

Comment: I'm not familiar with PDFBox API, I assume you can find this in the documentation.